# Modelling a business hierarchy

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a dashboard application where the user can navigate up and down through a hierarchy of 'business entity' and view data for that entity.

The hierarchy is as follows

```
       Company
    |           |
 Office DepartmentGroup
               |
    |   Department
          |
    Section
        |
    Employee
```

How can I best model this using objects. I have the idea that I would have an IEntity interface like:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int EntityKey { get; set; }
    string EntityCode { get; set; }
    string EntityName { get; set; }
    List<IEntity> Children { get; set; }
    List<IEntity> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

How should I model my concrete classes to impose this structure?

Comment: Do you really have multiple parents?

Comment: It seems, you should model them using composition

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the hierarchy is not just linear, a Section is either a subset of Department, or it can be a subset of Department associated with an Office (e.g. Department of IT, Office of London, Section structure could be IT - London, IT - Northampton etc (associated with an office) or it could be IT 1st Line, IT 2nd Line etc (not associated with an office)

Comment: +1 for this case. I'd like to get the better description about the hierarchy if possible.

Comment: OK, a full description of the hierarchy:

A single Company can be analysed by Offices (physical locations: London, Cambridge, Oxford), or by DepartmentGroups (IT, Accounting, Admin etc). DepartmentGroups can be separated into Departments (Helpdesk (IT), Development (IT), Reception (Admin) etc). A section is always associated with a department, and can also be associated with an office (Helpdesk (IT) London, Helpdesk (IT) Cambridge.... or can be just a subdivision of department: Frontline Helpdesk (IT), 2nd Line Helpdesk (IT)...).
An employee is a member of a section.

Answer (score 0):

My concern here would be that having a reference to IEntity removes the benefits of referencing a list of a concrete type. If a Department can only contain Sections then I would have a property that was an `IList<Department>` (or `IList<IDepartment>` if you're commitment-shy).

IMHO, there are more problems with an open and generic model (`IList<IEntity>`) that are not necessarily worth the benefit of the flexibility it provides.